# Rails Devise 401 from Safari Extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, safari-extension

I'm trying to make a simple $.ajax request to a Rails app running locally.

The request works without any issues from the console but when I make the call from the safari extension the app returns a 401 Unauthorized. I'm not sure if I need to create an api token for each user and pass that in the url string to authenticate or if there's a simple reason why devise is not processing the request even though I'm logged in. My guess is that the culprit is the before filter I have on my controller which looks like this:

```
before_filter: authenticate_user!
```

But again, I get the 401 when I am signed in to the app. Just for reference, here's the call I'm making from the extension:

```
$.ajax({                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                type: 'GET',                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/playlists.json?callback=?,                                                                                                                                              
                dataType: 'jsonp',                                                                                                                                                                                                
                success: function(data) { console.log(data); },                                                                                                                                                                                       
                error: function() { console.log('Uh Oh!'); },
                jsonp: 'jsonp', 
                crossdomain: true                                                                                                                                               
            });
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out. The cookie being set was set to expire after 'session' which basically means that as soon as you navigate away from the page the session is no longer there. Thus the extension did not have access to this extension cookie. The key was to set an expiration date by default on the session cookie which you can do like this in config/initializers/session_store.rb:

```
 YourApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, { 
    :key => '_yourapp_session',
    :expire_after => 60*24*60*60
}
```

You can read more about cookie types here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie